# Set field value with formik to react-select component from external button

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-select

I have a formik form that containa `react-select` field so My issue is that i have another fields and buttons that can affect the default value of the `react-select` component, I tried to use the setFieldValue function form `formik` but this indeed change the form value but the option in the select is not displayed

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-mendeleev-3bcc4?file=/src/App.js) de codeSandbox I did with a simple example of what I'm tryng to do

Any idea about this

Comment: Your link is broken

Comment: thanks the link is already available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, 
On clicking the `Add option` button, a new option should be added in the options list and that option will also be marked as selected.

For that, I did the following changes

> 1. Created the options list as `useState` hook so that we can alter list accordingly

```js
 const [options, setOptions] = useState([
    { value: "options 1", label: "option 1" },
    { value: "options 2", label: "option 2" }
  ]);
```

and call `setOptions` in `handleAddOption` function.

```js
 const handleAddOption = () => {
    setOptions([...options, { label: "test option", value: "test option" }]);
    return setFieldValue("name", "test option");
  };
```

> 2. I changed `value` prop in `Select` field. so that correct value can be passed to the function. because you are passing `name` in `setFieldValue` function.

```js
 value={defaultValue(options, values.name)}
```

working example https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-clarke-4pjdy

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful, I added the change and I found that every time I add a value that already exist in the option list, generate a duplicate, but i solved using lodash with the _.uniq method to the option state